# Working example of chrome extension with native app messaging

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying out Chrome's native messaging API but I haven't been able to get it to work.

The documentation has a link to this [example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/), but it's not an example of an extension, it's a chrome packaged app.

I've tried modifying it to work as an extension, but I lack the experience to get it right.

Can someone please give me an example of a chrome extension that can work with a native app?

Thank you.

Comment: how can i download this whole example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, the example you link to is fairly simple and does not use any app-specific API.
Thus, it should be easy to convert it to an extension by slightly modifying the manifest:

```
// Replace that:
"app": {
    ...
},

// With this:
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    //"default_icon": {
    //    "19": "img/icon19.png",
    //    "38": "img/icon38.png"
    //},
    "default_popup": "main.html"
},
```

<sub>(I haven't tested it myself, but it should work...)</sub>

Comment: That was my thought as well.  Unfortunately, it didn't work. :(

Comment: @Person93: What platform are you trying this on ?

Comment: @Person93: I tried that on Windows and it works fine. Did you follow the instructions for your OS (on the example's README) ? What exactly is not working ? What are the exact steps you took to implement the example ?

Comment: I didn't see OS specific instructions.  I will have to take another look.

Comment: @Person93: In **[README.txt](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/README.txt)** there are two sections: **On Windows**, **On Mac and Linux**

Comment: Yes, I just got this working a few days ago.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Person93: Nice ! (If this answer helped you, please consider accepting and/or upcoting it.)

Comment: How can i download this example?